# Getting images from CBZ archive

Tags: android, unzip, zip

I need to get images from CBZ archives and display them in my PageViewer. At the moment I'm unzipping the CBZ archive and placing the images on the SD-Card which is so slow... It takes 8 seconds to unzip one image. 
Is there any other way to do this? I don't need to unzip the CBZ archive, but just get the images to display them. Any suggestions would be great to speed this up.

Code to unzip the archive:

```
package nl.MarcVale.ComicViewer;

/**
 * Created by Marc on 23-8-13.
 */
import android.util.Log;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipInputStream;


public class DecompressZip {
private String _zipFile;
private String _location;

public DecompressZip(String zipFile, String location) {
    _zipFile = zipFile;
    _location = location;

    _dirChecker("");
}

public void unzip() {
    try  {
        FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(_zipFile);
        ZipInputStream zin = new ZipInputStream(fin);
        ZipEntry ze = null;
        while ((ze = zin.getNextEntry()) != null) {
            Log.v("Decompress", "Unzipping " + ze.getName());

            if(ze.isDirectory()) {
                _dirChecker(ze.getName());
            } else {
                FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(_location + ze.getName());
                for (int c = zin.read(); c != -1; c = zin.read()) {
                    fout.write(c);
                }

                zin.closeEntry();
                fout.close();
            }

        }
        zin.close();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        Log.e("Decompress", "unzip", e);
    }

}

private void _dirChecker(String dir) {
    File f = new File(_location + dir);

    if(!f.isDirectory()) {
        f.mkdirs();
    }
}
}
```

Edit: Some more code after a answer:

I'm creating the zipFile to downscale it, because the images are way too big. I'm getting a OutOfMemory exception at the first decodeFromStream line.

```
ZipFile zipFile = null;
        try {
            zipFile = new ZipFile("/sdcard/file.cbz");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        for (Enumeration<? extends ZipEntry> e = zipFile.entries(); e.hasMoreElements(); ) {
            ZipEntry ze = e.nextElement();
            try {



                //Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(zipFile.getInputStream(ze));
                Bitmap bm = decodeScaledBitmapFromSdCard(zipFile.getInputStream(ze),width,height);


                pages.add(bm);
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }

    public static Bitmap decodeScaledBitmapFromSdCard(InputStream filePath,
                                                      int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

        // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
        final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        //BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, options);
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(filePath, null, options);

        // Calculate inSampleSize
        options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

        // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(filePath, null, options);
    }

    public static int calculateInSampleSize(
            BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
        // Raw height and width of image
        final int height = options.outHeight;
        final int width = options.outWidth;
        int inSampleSize = 1;

        if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

            // Calculate ratios of height and width to requested height and width
            final int heightRatio = Math.round((float) height / (float) reqHeight);
            final int widthRatio = Math.round((float) width / (float) reqWidth);

            // Choose the smallest ratio as inSampleSize value, this will guarantee
            // a final image with both dimensions larger than or equal to the
            // requested height and width.
            inSampleSize = heightRatio < widthRatio ? heightRatio : widthRatio;
        }

        return inSampleSize;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [ZipFile](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/zip/ZipFile.html). It gives you an  `InputStream` for each entry, which you can decode using [BitmapFactory.decodeStream](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html#decodeStream%28java.io.InputStream%29).

```
ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(<filename>);
for (Enumeration<? extends ZipEntry> e = zipFile.entries(); e.hasMoreElements(); ) {
    ZipEntry ze = e.nextElement();
    Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(zipFile.getInputStream(ze));

}
```

Comment: Because I dont have a idea how to use that. Can you help?

Comment: I confused ZipInputStream and ZipFile, I changed the answer

Comment: Sound prommising, going to try it out now.

Comment: I tried doing this, but can't seem to do it. Is there a possibility to get a direct location (string location) to the files inside the zip? Because I need to downscale the images.

Comment: One of the `decodeStream` methods take a `BitmapFactory.Options`. You can `getInputStream` and decode the stream twice, (one with `inJustDecodeBounds`, the second with  `inSampleSize` set).

Comment: I'm editing my question to include some more code. Then I can explain it a bit better, because I got a outOfMemory with that. Edit: The edit is done.

Comment: It is probably not related but I'm a bit surprised that you can decode a stream twice (I would have used a new stream from the same ZipEntry).
Does the OutOfMemoryError happen on the first image ? 
'...at the first decodeFromStream line', you mean the decodeStream wich does only measure the image ?

Comment: Okay, I tried something out and the OutOfMemory is because I'm adding the Bitmaps to a arraylist with all the bitmaps. Is there a way that I can save the bitmaps temporary? Then I won't have this problem.

Comment: You can : 1) scan the zip with an `ZipInputStream` to get the names of the all the entries, then 2) load each image when you need to display it from a `ZipFile`, [getEntry(name)](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/zip/ZipFile.html#getEntry%28java.lang.String%29) then [getInputStream(entry)](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/zip/ZipFile.html#getInputStream%28java.util.zip.ZipEntry%29) and recycle the Bitmap you don't need anymore.

Comment: Okay, I did add the part where I'm adding the names of all the entries, but I don't know excactly how I can add the image with the entry name. Can you help?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36110/discussion-between-marc-and-bwt)